# Write a python script that crawls through a folder and lists each file and size

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm struggling to find a way to write a script that will go through folders of ArcGIS data and report back the name and size of every feature in the folder to a csv file so that I can create a directory of the data stored within. The data stored within the folders are individual feature classes alongside whole geodatabases.

Comment: I don't know anything about geodatabases but look at: (1.) [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), (2.) [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat)

Comment: The title suggests you want to examine files' size but the question suggests that you want to examine files' contents... what do you want to do, exactly?

Comment: I would like a script to record the name and size of every feature class stored within a particular folder. It will probably need to use the arpy version of the os.walk function (arpy.da.walk) but I'm not sure how to also make the script write the feature size as well.

Comment: Which part have you been struggling with? Have you written any code, and what do you need help with?

Answer (score 2):

Try glob and os together:

```
import os
import glob

outputfile = 'GIS_Directory'

#Creates header row of output csv file
with open(outputfile +'.csv', 'a') as summary:
    summary.write('File Name,File Size' + '\n') 

#Loop walks through all files of designated extension
#and writes new line to output csv file
for file in glob.glob(r'<pathname>\*.<extension>'):
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(file)

    with open(outputfile +'.csv', 'a') as summary:
        summary.write(str(filename) + ',' + 
                      str(filesize) + '\n')
```

Note that getsize reports the filesize in bytes, so you should adjust the code to calculate it for the units that you want outputted. As is, you would have to repeat the for loop for each extension type in your folder; I am not sure which extensions are used for individual feature classes and geodatabases.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a file geodatabase feature class's size with `arcpy`. Rather, you will need to use ArcObjects. More details [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/24242/8104).

Otherwise, listing the feature classes in a file geodatabase is straight forward with [Walk (arcpy.da)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000023000000):

```
import arcpy
import os

workspace = r"C:\Users\OWNER\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"
feature_classes = []

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```